# Is it correct to say before he come or before he came

Tags: grammaticality

1/

- Did he paint the wall before his friend came?
  (OR)
- Did he paint the wall before his friend come?

2/

- Had he painted the wall before his friend came?
  (OR)
- Had he painted the wall before his friend come?

Answer (score 1):

For all "standard" varieties of English, only *before he **came*** is valid. But you will sometimes hear ***come*** in similar "Past Tense" contexts in the UK...

> 1: *We were in the pub last night when this guy **come** over and **picked** a fight with us*

It's worth noting that although the first highlighted verb there *looks* like an "Unmarked Infinitive" (the non-inflected "base" form, but without the "infinitive marker" ***to***), it's probably better analysed as just a different *pronunciation* of Past Tense ***came***. I say that because you'll also sometimes hear the true "Present Tense used as Past" version *used consistently...*

> 2: *...when this guy **comes** over and **picks** a fight with us* <==Ungrammatical, but not uncommon

...but I doubt I've *ever* heard the permutation ***comes*** + ***picked***. And although both the above sound perfectly "natural" to me (albeit quite obviously "ungrammatical"), I can't say the same for #1 with other verbs. For example, I'm sure I've never heard either of...

> 3: * *...when this guy **walk** over and **picked** a fight with us* <==VERY non-idiomatic!
>    4: * *...when this guy **walks** over and **picked** a fight with us* <==VERY non-idiomatic!

Note that #1 and #2 above are primarily associated with *uneducated* speakers (or [semi-]facetious imitation thereof) - it's not particularly associated with any specific *regional* dialects.

---

TL;DR: The only "grammatically correct" version is...

> 5: *We were in the pub last night when this guy **came** over and picked a fight with us*

But "uneducated" native speakers often use Present as Past. And with certain *specific* verbs *(**come / came, run / ran**),* some people just enunciate the Present tense version even when they're using the explicit Past form with other verbs

Answer (score -1):

About part number one of your question:

I've just searched for sentences like these in literature and found no one with "come" but with "came" found some examples:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sense_and_Sensibility :

> "Did you see them off, before you came away?"

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maia_(novel) :

> "Did you know Occula before you came to Bekla?"

https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/8713217-the-eden-legacy :

> ‘Did you ever get to Gori before the Russians came?’ he asked Davit, in Georgian.

About second part of your question:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duty_and_Desire :

> Had Georgiana warned him before he came up?

https://books.google.de/books/about/The_Godling_Chronicles.html?id=1UnGNAEACAAJ&redir_esc=y :

> Had I found out before I had come to know the boy, I am unsure how I would have reacted.”

So as I can see by examples from literature you need to use version with "came" in this situation or use "had come" like last example.

Comment: Too many 'examples from literature', not enough explanation.

Comment: I think, examples are useful too, this answer maybe have poor explanation, but give people base for thinking about problem.